# Как разбить поле адрес на улица, дом, корпус, квартира(номер офиса)?

Tags: magento

Стоит задача, чтобы в стандартной форме checkout(оформления заказа) разбить поле адрес на составляющие(улица, дом, корпус, квартира(номер офиса)), чтобы каждое поле было отдельным input`ом. До этого с мадженто дело не имел, от слова "совсем".
Пожалуйста направьте в правильном направлении по-пунктам что и, самое главное, по каким путям регистрировать и переопределять новый компонент, или можно изменить текущий, заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: открыть файл с версткой этой страницы и добавить нужные `input`

Comment: Я тоже так думал, пока не столкнулся с этой системой управления. Тут используются UI компоненты которые определяются очень странным способом

Comment: может поможет https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142519/how-to-customize-the-customer-registration-form